# Merging Binary Trees in Java

Tags: java, binary-tree

I've been working on "Merge Two Binary Trees" for hours now, and I can't figure out why my code isn't working.  I am given tree t1 as [1,3,2,5] and tree t2 as [2,1,3,null,4,null,7] and I have to merge the two trees by summing overlapping nodes and avoiding nulls where possible, so the result should be [3,4,5,5,4,null,7].  Rather than creating a new tree like I'm supposed to, I'm rewriting tree t1 to have the desired results.  My code is as follows:

```
/**
 * Definition for a binary tree node.
 * public class TreeNode {
 *     int val;
 *     TreeNode left;
 *     TreeNode right;
 *     TreeNode(int x) { val = x; }
 * }
 */
class Solution {
    public TreeNode mergeTrees(TreeNode t1, TreeNode t2) {
        traversal(t1, t2);
        return t1;
    }

    public void traversal(TreeNode t1, TreeNode t2) {
        if(t2 == null) return;
        if(t1 == null)
            t1 = new TreeNode(0);
        t1.val += t2.val;
        traversal(t1.left, t2.left);
        traversal(t1.right, t2.right);
    }
}
```

My code runs with no errors, and my end result is [3,4,5,5], which is obviously wrong.  It seems like the line

```
t1 = new TreeNode(0);
```

is not doing what I want it to do.  I want it to change the current node from being null to having a value of 0, a null left node, and a null right node, so that in the next iteration, the program will iterate the newly created left node which is null.

I tried recreating the entire thing (including class / method declarations) in my IDE in order to play around with it and do some debugging, so I could edit my full code into this post if needed, but I also can't figure out how to do

```
TreeNode(int val, TreeNode left, TreeNode right) {
  this.val = val;
  this.left = left;
  this.right = right;
}
```

when I want either the left or the right (but not both) to be null, so my full code isn't as clean as it should be.  In any case, can anyone help me figure out why my code is getting the wrong answer for the given input?

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem here is that the code below doesn't really do what you intended to do.

```
public void traversal(TreeNode t1, TreeNode t2) {
. . .
if(t1 == null)
    t1 = new TreeNode(0);
. . .
```

Here you change your **local copy** of the reference to point to the new object. You **don't change the original object**. In fact, you cannot do that in a different method than the original method where an object was initially created. Please see [java pass by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value).

So basically you create a new `TreeNode` which is not connected to the parent node. You have to do it manually, keeping track of parent nodes as well.

Comment: In that case, shouldn't "t1.val += t2.val;" also only affect the local copy of the object?  My output was different from my input, so does this mean that what you said only applies to the object itself, but the object's fields can be updated non-locally?

Comment: Yes, `"t1.val += t2.val;"` only affects local copy of the object, if t1 is local copy. If `t1` is a reference to the original object, then you can modify `t1.val`

Comment: Sorry, but I am still confused.  Why did my output give 3 as the new value for the root node from the mergeTrees method, when ```t1.val += t2.val;``` should not have affected t1 from the mergeTrees method?  My understanding is that there was an original t1 which was passed as an argument to mergeTrees, so mergeTrees has a local copy of t1, and then that local copy was passed to the traversal method as an argument, so traversal a local copy of t1.  So then there are a total of at least 3 t1 objects, none of which can update the values of the others unless utilizing a return statement.

Comment: Basically, ```traversal(t1, t2);``` should have done literally nothing to the mergeTrees method, so my entire code should be equivalent to just 1 line saying ```return t1;```, but if that were the case then my output should have been [1,3,2,5], but my output instead was actually [3,4,5,5].